# Получение через comport строки в неизменном виде

Tags: кодировка, serial

Одна программа передает другой программе строку через компорт.
На передатчике создаю строку:

```
string stroka="\u00E2\u005E\u0040\u0049\u0021\u0043\u0042\u0000\u00C6\u002e";
```

Как мне на приемнике после приема строки получить такую же точно строку? И чтобы это была именно строка а не массив байтов. Массив байтов я уже получил, но как из него сделать такую строку - не пойму. Все что пробовал упирается в кодировки а кодировки это значит замена некоторых моих данных кодами непечатаемых символов.

Comment: причем передаются все байты, я их считал по количеству в буфере. А любая кодировка искажает их... или я не нашел нужную кодировку. Но написано что строка это набор  utf-16. Пытаюсь делать строку через Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer); так она выбрасывает все нули, моя строка становится короче в два раза, превращается в \E25E\4049\2143\4200\C62E и если встречает неизвестные utf16 коды - заменяет их байтами непечатаемого символа FFFD

Comment: нашел, string Convert(byte[] data) 
{ 
    char[] characters = data.Select(b => (char)b).ToArray(); 
    return new string(characters); 
}